# How could I use VAR model for nonstationary series?

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, vector-error-correction-model, eviews

I have five independent variables: `oil` (stationary at level), `f` (stationary at level), `k` (stationary after differencing twice) , `pd` (stationary after differencing), `m` (stationary after differencing) and dependent variable `rc` (stationary at level). How could use or write the model on Eviews? Are my inputs displayed in the graph below correct? And could I use vecm?

[image]

Comment: You should add more information about what you are trying to achieve with your model. Then it may be possible to give a better answer that the one I gave below.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that you have one dependent variable and five independents, then you need to use simple regression and stay away from VAR and VECM.

Comment: Thank you mpiktas ...I didn't understand  why I don't have to use var and what details do you need to view please?

Comment: You use VAR when there is more than one endogenous (dependent) variable among the variables you have. VAR allows for mutual dependence, e.g. when $rc$ depends on (lagged) $oil$ and $oil$ depends on (lagged) $rc$. There are as many equations in a VAR as there are dependent variables. If only one variable is endogenous and all the other are exogenous (independent), then your VAR will only have one equation and thus will no longer be a VAR but rather a simple regression.

Comment: yes i have two endogenous rc and ris but i thought i have to test each of them in separate way rc and ris are returns for two mutual funds an i want to test if the exogenous variable will cause the endogenous by using Granger causality